# Python: How to use a similar operator to "or"/"in" in a list

Tags: python

I have a quiz program that asks people questions. These questions are stored in a **.extend function** to add them to my questions list. The same applies with my answers to each question.

```
Questions.extend (["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", etc... ])
Answers.extend (["Question 1's Answer", "Question 2's Answer", "Question 3's Answer", etc... ])
```

These questions are added to my list, they are asked one at a time and then are deleted from the list, using multiple modules.

So is it possible to be able to state three or four possible answers for Question 1, and for the other questions? So if the user types one of the four answers stated for Question 1, they will receive a correct message.

Comment: have you considered storing the possible answers in a list of lists ?

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: ooo sounds interesting. how would I do this? It sounds like I need something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

You maybe better off using a dict.

```
>>> testbank = {"question 1":["answer1a", "answer1b", "answer1c", "answer1d"],
...  "question n":["answerna", "answernb", "answernc", "answernd"]}
>>> testbank['question 1']
['answer1a', 'answer1b', 'answer1c', 'answer1d']
>>> def validate(answer, question):
...  if answer in testbank['question 1']:
...   print 'Correct!'
...  else:
...   print 'Try again.'
...
>>> answer = "answer1a"
>>> validate(answer, 'question 1')
Correct!
>>> wrongansw = 'foobar'
>>> validate(wrongansw, 'question 1')
Try again.
```

=========================

In lieu of your update on the requirement, you can use list of lists.

```
>>> answers = [["answer1a", "answer1b", "answer1c", "answer1d"],["answerna", "answernb", "answernc", "answernd"]]
>>> questions = ['question1','questionn']
>>> def validate(a,q):
...  if a in answers[questions.index('question1')]:
...   print 'Correct'
...  else:
...   print 'Try again'
...
>>> validate('foobar','question1')
Try again
>>> validate('answer1a','question1')
Correct
>>> validate('answer1b','question1')
Correct
```

Comment: yes, thats great, only I am using the .extend to add questions and answers. I am not entering it directly into a list, I am listing values/elements that will be inserted into a list.

Comment: Can you create a temp list and call extend('answer') on it for each answer to a question. Then extend that list to the Answers list?

Comment: Okay, is it possible for you to show me what you mean? I'm not quite sure what this would look like.

Comment: I've played around with it and have been able to setup my own version of a validator. Thanks :-)